# const reference confusion with specific example

Tags: c++

I have a class called counter and my assignment operator looks like this:

```
const counter& counter::operator=(const counter& y)
{
    count = y.count;
    return *this;
}
```

Now, my confusion stems from the return value:

```
const counter& counter:: ...
```

I think this means that the assignment operator for counter is supposed to return a const counter reference and since it's const that object should be immutable, but as far as I can tell it isn't.

Here's my counterTest code and I've commented in my concerns:

```
#include "counter.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    counter c; // c.count = 0

    c.Inc();  // c.count = 1
    c.Inc(); // c.count = 2

    counter c2;

    // Here I use my assignment operator so shouldn't c2 be immutable?
    c2 = c; // c3.count = 2

    // Why does this work?
    c2.Inc(); // c3.count = 3
    c2.Inc(); // c3.count = 4

    cout << "c = " << c.Count() << ", c2 = " << c2.Count()
            << endl; // prints: c = 2, c2 = 4
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you declare `c2`:

```
counter c2;
```

As you can see, it's not `const`. This will never change. Your assignment can't possibly change the `const`ness of `c2`.

In your assignment function, it is `*this` that refers to the object you're assigning to, not the return value. The return value is the value of the expression `c2 = c`. So if you tried to modify the result, perhaps with `(c2 = c).Inc()`, it wouldn't work, because the return value is `const`.

---

I notice that you seem to think `const counter& counter::` is the return type of the function. Actually, just `const counter&` is. The `counter::` part is a nested name specifier that says the `operator=` function is a member of the `counter` class.

```
const counter& counter::operator=(const counter& y)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 return type    scope   func name    parameters
```

Comment: Not a qualifier (that would be keywords like `const`) but the scope.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Well they're called qualified IDs. But sure, scope is a more friendly description.

Comment: Even if, what valid type would `const counter& counter::` or `const counter& counter` be?

Comment: @mb84 It's not a valid type at all. :)

Comment: ok, I think I've got it, the only change to c2 happens in the operator=(...) function and the return value is irrelevant to c2 in that regard. I'm only used to languages with "hardwired" assignment operators and this is terribly confusing:). I don't think counter:: is part of the return type, I felt that "const counter&" felt out of place so I was trying to give it better context to make things more clear but I managed to do the opposite!

Comment: @Baldur Yes, it is in general irrelevant. However, you *are* returning `*this`, so the return value is also `c2`. However, because it's a reference to `const`, you can't modify it.

Answer (score 0):

With

`const counter& counter::operator=(const counter& y)`

you simply change the meaning of the standard `operator=` which would be defined as `counter& counter::operator=(const counter& y)` in a way that you cannot concatenate it in this *special* form: `(a=b)=c`. Or also not `(a=b).Inc()`. But a normal `a=b=c` would be possible.

A variable has to be explicitely defined as `const` *before* you use any operator. It cannot get `const` *after* it depending on the return type. Therefore, like already said, you need to define c2 as const.

**Edit:**

And also you should consider writing an own *copy constructor*, because `const c2 = c` would only look like `operator=` is called, but in fact, the copy constructor is called (which in this case would be the default one which makes only a shallow copy of members).